# Unity 3rd person controller, rotation nightmare

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a MMO character controller like the one of this Youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOvf7gRO_aM

Basically, you use WASD to move around.
You can move the camera by mouse click and drag, and when moving, you character will now move in the new camera direction.
The thing is, i would like that when i press WASD, that the character (not the camera) would face the direction of the mouvement.

I tried to use this:

```
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 | Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0){
        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        character.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
```

The character was not facing the right direction, so i tried this

```
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 | Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0){
        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        character.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
    }
```

but that does not seem to work. I am a noob after all :D

Here is the full code of the controller's move part:

```
private void Move()
{
    moveFrontBack = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    moveLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveLeftRight, 0, moveFrontBack);
    movement = character.rotation * movement;
    characterController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);

    //Animation on move
    if (movement.magnitude != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
    }

    if (movement.magnitude == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
    }

    centerPoint.position = new Vector3(character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);

    //The place where things go south it seems
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 | Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
    {
        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        character.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
```

I had a previous version on the controller, without the change of camera with mouse, but the right character's behaviour facing the direction of the input:

```
    private void Move()
{
    moveFrontBack = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    moveLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveLeftRight, 0, moveFrontBack);

    characterController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);
    if (movement != Vector3.zero) transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
    if (movement.magnitude != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
    }

    if (movement.magnitude == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
    }


    playerCamera.position = new Vector3(character.position.x, character.position.y + yCamera, character.position.z + zCamera);
}
```

Also, here is the mousemoving part:

```
    void MouseTurnAround()
{
    zoom += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;

    if (zoom > zoomMin)
        zoom = zoomMin;

    if (zoom < zoomMax)
        zoom = zoomMax;

    playerCamera.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, zoom);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    }
    mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -60f, 60f);
    playerCamera.LookAt(centerPoint);
    centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
}
```

I don't really have more ideas, so maybe smart people can see what they can do ! Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I managed some kind of a mix of my 2 solutions, and parented my character to an empty gameobject, which receives the new rotations. Then, i leave the character be oriented to the movement with look rotation.

```
    private void Move()
{
    moveFrontBack = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    moveLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveLeftRight, 0, moveFrontBack);
    movement = character.rotation * movement;
    characterController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);

    //Animation on move
    if (movement.magnitude != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
    }

    if (movement.magnitude == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
    }

    centerPoint.position = new Vector3(character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);

    //Rotates the character to move towards new direction
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 | Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
    {
        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, centerPoint.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        character.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
    if (movement != Vector3.zero) lkModel.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
}
```